# Slow Boot time apt-daily-upgrade.service and apt-daily.service on Xubuntu 18.04 - ASUS K70IO laptop

Tags: boot, xubuntu, asus, services, systemd-networkd

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04, yet recently my

> old laptop is very slow to boot

.

I've been hunting on the internet but I am unable to find any solution.

Please help,

```
ASUS K70IO
NVIDIA GeForce GT 120M
320GB scsi HDD
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5900  @ 2.20GHz
2 x 2GiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 2048 MHz (0,5 ns)
```

$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

$ systemd-analyze blame

```
1min 48.606s apt-daily-upgrade.service
     48.437s apt-daily.service
     11.508s dev-sda6.device
      8.186s networkd-dispatcher.service
      8.082s keyboard-setup.service
      6.290s NetworkManager.service
      5.793s grub-common.service
      5.128s udisks2.service
      4.815s snapd.service
      4.327s accounts-daemon.service
      4.175s apparmor.service
      4.040s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.674s thermald.service
      3.411s avahi-daemon.service
      3.376s pppd-dns.service
      3.374s gpu-manager.service
      3.373s rsyslog.service
      2.491s colord.service
      2.136s systemd-udevd.service
      2.105s systemd-journal-flush.service
      1.413s systemd-logind.service
      1.398s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.354s apport.service
```

$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @27.327s

└─multi-user.target @27.327s

└─getty.target @27.327s

```
└─getty@tty1.service @27.327s
  └─system-getty.slice @27.325s
    └─setvtrgb.service @26.730s +594ms
      └─systemd-user-sessions.service @24.850s +661ms
        └─network.target @24.770s
          └─NetworkManager.service @18.479s +6.290s
            └─dbus.service @15.872s
              └─basic.target @15.858s
                └─sockets.target @15.858s
                  └─snapd.socket @15.838s +19ms
                    └─sysinit.target @15.781s
                      └─apparmor.service @11.605s +4.175s
                        └─local-fs.target @11.598s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @11.598s
                            └─keyboard-setup.service @3.516s +8.082s
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @3.463s
                                └─system.slice @3.462s
```

$ sudo lshw -short

```
ASUS                        system      K70IO (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0                          bus         K70IO
/0/0                        memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5900  @ 2.20GHz
/0/4/5                      memory      64KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                      memory      2MiB L2 cache
/0/1f                       memory      4GiB System Memory
/0/1f/0                     memory      2GiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 2048 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/1f/1                     memory      2GiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 2048 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/1/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk        320GB ST9320423AS
/0/1/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume      100MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2   volume      140GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3    /dev/sda3   volume      832MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4    /dev/sda4   volume      156GiB Extended partition
/0/1/0.0.0/4/5  /dev/sda5   volume      20GiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4/6  /dev/sda6   volume      129GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4/7  /dev/sda7   volume      7812MiB Linux swap volume
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I don't believe it's the answer.especially as these two are not the only thing...      8.186s networkd-dispatcher.service
      8.082s keyboard-setup.service
      6.290s NetworkManager.service